# 'Experiment DEAD got' warnings in H2O DAI log

Tags: driverless-ai

I see lots of 'Experiment DEAD got' warnings in the H2O DAI experiment log.   What does this mean ?

2019-10-10 10:37:11,441 C:  D:109.4GB M:6.0GB 15175 WARNING: Experiment DEAD got 426a3c9c-eafe-11e9-8651-9cb6d060f074 server process (pids were: [])    [=#h2oai-426a3c9c].

Comment: hi @nasica88 could you include full details about how to reproduce what you are seeing: what version of DAI you are using, if you upgraded between versions, what settings you used to run your experiment and a description of your dataset column types and stats. thanks!

Comment: This happened in DAI v1.7.0 and was addressed in v1.8.0.  Thanks.